# The problem of creating a relationship between database tables in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

*Hello*
I wrote a ticketing system for site support and created a ticket class and a ticket response class in the model

**MODEL.py :**

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    status_choices = (
        ('Active','Active'),
        ('Completed', 'Completed'),
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
    )
    ticket_number = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name='Title')
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Description')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='created_by')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ticket_status = models.CharField(max_length=15,choices=status_choices)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```
class TicketReply(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Description')
    ticket_user = models.ManyToManyField('Ticket')
    date_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

And I created a form to create and update tickets

**FORMS.py :**

```
class CreateTicketForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = ['title','description']

class UplateTicketModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TicketReply
        fields = ['description']
        widgets = {
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'rows': 4,
            }),
        }

        labels = {
            'description': 'Reply',
        }

        error_messages = {
            'description': {
                'required': 'Enter the description'
            }
        }
```

And finally, I wrote the two function so that the user can create and track the ticket.

**VIEW.py :**

```
def create_ticket(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateTicketForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            var = form.save(commit=False)
            var.created_by = request.user
            var.ticket_status = 'Pending'
            var.save()
            messages.info(request,'Your ticket has been successfully.')

            return redirect('all-tickets')
        else:
            messages.warning(request,'Somthing went wrong.')
            return redirect('create-ticket')
    else:
        form = CreateTicketForm()
        context = {
            'form': form
        }
        return render(request,'apps/user_panel/tickets/create_ticket.html',context)


def ticket_details(request,pk):
    ticket = Ticket.objects.get(pk=pk)
    t = User.objects.get(username=ticket.created_by)
    tickets_per_user = t.created_by.all()
    reply_ticket: TicketReply = TicketReply.objects.filter(ticket_user=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UplateTicketModelForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            var = form.save(commit=False)
            var.assigned_to = request.user
            var.save()
            messages.info(request,'Your reply ticket has been successfully.')

            return redirect('all-tickets')
    else:
        form = UplateTicketModelForm(request.POST)

        context = {
            'ticket': ticket,
            'tickets_per_user': tickets_per_user,
            'reply_ticket': reply_ticket,
            'form': form
        }
        return render(request, 'apps/user_panel/tickets/ticket_details.html', context)
```

There is no problem when the user is answered from the Django admin panel. Because you can choose the main ticket.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNTxc.png)
But when the answer is sent through the form, there is a problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzXGn.png)

I could not add a few items in the view

1. I will make a connection after the support answer to the ticket.The user_ticket field should be selected automatically.
2. Create a connection so that after the supporter's response, the ticket will change from pending to complete, and if the user responds, it will change to pending.

**Please help, thank you**

I tried to create a relation between the database tables in Django but I was not successful.

Comment: According to documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) the manytomany field doesn't need the '', just use the class. ticket_user = models.ManyToManyField(Ticket). also you need to save() both instances before assign, maybe that is the thing with your code.